# Creating a slice of a matrix from a vector in Numpy

Tags: performance, numpy, indexing, vectorization, matrix-indexing

Provided that I have a matrix `A` of size 5 by 4, also a vector `b` of length 5 whose element indicates how many values I need in the corresponding row of matrix `A`. That means each value in `b` is upper-bounded by the size of second dimension of `A`. My problem is how to make a slice of a matrix given an vector, which is a complex-version of taking an integer-valued elements of a vector by writing `vector[:n]`

For example, this can be implemented with a loop over A's rows:

```
import numpy
A=numpy.arange(20).reshape((5,4))
b=numpy.array([0, 3, 3, 2, 3])
output=A[0, :b[0]]
for i in xrange(1, A.shape[0]):
    output=numpy.concatenate((output, A[i, :b[i]]), axis=0)
# output is array([ 4,  5,  6,  8,  9, 10, 12, 13, 16, 17, 18])
```

The computation efficiency of this loop can be fairly low when dealing with a very large array. Furthermore, my purpose is to apply this in Theano eventually without a `scan` operation. I want to avoid using a loop to make a slice given an vector.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another good setup for using [`NumPy broadcasting`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html)!

```
A[b[:,None] > np.arange(A.shape[1])]
```

**Sample run**

1) Inputs :

```
In [16]: A
Out[16]: 
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
       [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
       [ 8,  9, 10, 11],
       [12, 13, 14, 15],
       [16, 17, 18, 19]])

In [17]: b
Out[17]: array([0, 3, 3, 2, 3])
```

2) Use broadcasting to create mask for selection :

```
In [18]: b[:,None] > np.arange(A.shape[1])
Out[18]: 
array([[False, False, False, False],
       [ True,  True,  True, False],
       [ True,  True,  True, False],
       [ True,  True, False, False],
       [ True,  True,  True, False]], dtype=bool)
```

3) Finally use `boolean-indexing` for selecting elems off `A` :

```
In [19]: A[b[:,None] > np.arange(A.shape[1])]
Out[19]: array([ 4,  5,  6,  8,  9, 10, 12, 13, 16, 17, 18])
```

Answer (score 0):

You could speed up the loop by collecting values in a list, and doing just one `concatenate`:

```
In [126]: [A[i,:j] for i,j in enumerate(b)]
Out[126]: 
[array([], dtype=int32),
 array([4, 5, 6]),
 array([ 8,  9, 10]),
 array([12, 13]),
 array([16, 17, 18])]

In [127]: np.concatenate([A[i,:j] for i,j in enumerate(b)])
Out[127]: array([ 4,  5,  6,  8,  9, 10, 12, 13, 16, 17, 18])
```